# Android non-static string to Static string error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, static, non-static

I am building a database class in android which gathers String non-static data from the getIntent().getStringExtra(name) function.
The value of this i am putting in a simple string variable (Non-Static).

When im trying to use it inside a static string, i get an error - "Cannot make static reference to a non static field".

How can i solve this? Here is my code:

```
package ent.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SetSql extends Activity{

String saveExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("save");

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_SAVE = "save_name";
public static final String KEY_STADUIM = "stadium_size";
public static final String KEY_FINANCE = "total_money";
public static final String KEY_PLAYERS = "players";

private static String DATABASE_NAME = "save" + saveExtra;
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "save_data";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}

}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
String saveExtra = null; 
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "save" ;
```

In OnCreate

```
String saveExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("save");
DATABASE_NAME += saveExtra;
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason for declaring saveExtra variable inside and outside the onCreate?? Couldn't we just use the same instance of saveExtra(that has already been declared outside) inside the onCreate method.

Comment: This is because static variables of a class will be initialized before any other variables in the class. So initializing a static variable with some other non-static variable is not possible as the non-static variable will be initialized only after the static variable is initialized. Refer http://www.javatutorialhub.com/wiki/All_about_%22static%22

Comment: There might be a problem if your SetSql activity is instantiated more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Your static variable `DATABASE_NAME` is initialized as soon as your SetSql class is loaded, whereas the instance variable `saveExtra` is initialized only when an instance is created.

You could set `DATABASE_NAME` value in the SetSql class constructor but beware that it would impact **all** instances of SetSql, not just the one who received the intent.

IMHO, the simplest option would be to set `DATABASE_NAME` as an instance variable like `saveExtra`.

Comment: Im not sure i got it.. Both variables are set outside of the DbHelper class. whats wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread, you are using an inner-class. The indentation is a bit wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a static "getDatabaseName" methode to access your string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `String saveExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("save");`
 from Activity level, and write it into your `onCreate()`.

Just declare your variable saveExtra at Activity level.

Comment: Do you mean instead of declaring it outside the Activity oncreate method to declare saveExtra inside it? its not actually working :(

Comment: Declare - No Problem,...line `getIntent().getStringExtra("save");` write in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String saveExtra =null;
```

in

```
onCreate
```

use this

```
saveExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("save");
```